# Laravel 5.6. Set worker for 2 queues with priority ratio

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-queue

I have 2 queues. `high-priority` and `normal-priority`.

If I run the worker for both of them the `high-priority` will be always working and `normal-priority` will be significantly overflow.

I can't create 2 workers. Jobs there are using the same "resource" (not important what exactly), that can't be accessed by 2 jobs at the same time.

Is it possible somehow to define ratio for the worker. Like 70% chance to take from the `high-priority` and 30% from the `normal-priority`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's impossible to do in a standard way with Laravel.